# Importing an animated model into Three.JS

Tags: three.js

I'm modelling in Maya 2010, and I want to import the animated model that I have into Three.JS. What's the recommended pipeline for exporting out of Maya and then importing into Three.JS?

Answer (score 1):

@theodox, why is it a duplicate, he's not asking about JSON he's asking what the best course of action is.

My recommendation after a lot of toying around would be:
Make sure your model is correct/frozen etc. No unused bones and such. Remove unused influences. Then Export using OpenCollada and use ColladaLoader.js to load your model.

To give you a few headers to look at for javascript take a look at an extensive test I made for a bug I found.
www.mariusposthumus.nl/webgl

Hope it helps!